# Is there any evidence that Lana Beniko's character was based on Obi-Wan Kenobi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic, character-similarity

A friend recently pointed out to me that Beniko is an anagram of Kenobi. In addition, [Lana](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lana_Beniko), despite being a Sith, follows the path of the light so the choices she makes seem to be more in line with Ben's.

So is there any further similarities between these two characters? Have any Bioware devs indicated any intentional similarities besides the name?

Comment: Hmm. If only the leftover letters were also an anagram...

Comment: The choices she makes are in line with the player character, and she approves of certain dark side choices too. (opting to not disable the reactor on Zakuul damaged by Vaylin right after being rescued from the cryo chamber at the start of KOTFE), so she isn't exactly following the light.

Comment: By her own description (in conversation with Master Gnost-Dural in the Republic denouement to *Onslaught*) Lana emphatically does not follow the path of the light. She believes that the strong should rule, and inevitably will, and that ambition and the pursuit of personal power are worthwhile. She's just more patient, pragmatic, and shrewd than the stereotypical Sith.

Answer (score -1):

She is more grey Sith, than light Sith (ex. she, without hesitation, killed Kovach). Light Siths are differed in to two groups - those who in fact returned to Jedi way of life and light side and those who are very pragmatic and choosing peaceful way, but they are still loyal to Sith Empire. Lana misused Theron, killed Kovach and used various less-than-honourable practices to defend Empire, but she despise stupid cruelty. Despite anagram, I think she is more like darker version of Qui-Gon of Sith Empire.

Comment: This is a nice answer but it is grounded in your personal opinion whereas the question is more looking for an official response on this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed last part. In that case, no. I think there is no connection and its nothing more than easter egg (probably).